# Sample-By-Sample Linear Prediction

Tags: algorithms, real-time, linear-prediction

As I understand it and have it currently implemented, linear prediction [via Burg's method or the autocorrelation method] is a block algorithm. Hence, there will be latency involved because one must first save a block of samples to use in the analysis -- even if the model order is low.

But are there any sample by sample implementations of linear prediction? Are they less robust to noise?

Edit: To be clear, I am really looking for a sample by sample estimation of the autoregressive polynomial coefficients in order to do inverse filtering. Does such a thing exist?

Edit: Thanks to RBJ for pointing out my conflation of terms.

Comment: The delay should only bother you at the very beginning of processing where the buffer block is empty. But once it is filled, then you can update your prediction with each new incoming sample, hence real time prediction. In other words, forward linear prediction (predicting a future value based on past stored samples) is a causal system that can be implemented in real time.

Comment: well, *"real-time"* processing certainly need not be synonymous with *"sample-by-sample"* processing.  there's no reason in the world (as long as your real-time DSP has the ability to execute a conditional branch instruction) that you cannot process blocks of samples in a real-time DSP system.  in fact, that's what i normally do (usually blocks of 32 audio samples, which is less than a millisecond of delay).

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson True. That is what I usually do too, and it seems to work out. With today's hardware, I can usually get away with some pretty large ffts. I should have worded my question differently.

Comment: well, dunno *"Burg's method"*, but i do know *Levison-Durbin recursion* to do LPC.  i see no reason that cannot be done on blocks to get your coefficients and the coefficients can be slewed, on a sample-by-sample basis between blocks.

Comment: can you use the code in this [Levison-Durbin recursion](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/24325/4346) and supply it with auto-correlation computed by some other straight-forward code?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson That is essentially what I do now, the problem is, even if I slide one sample in and slide one sample out, I still have to recompute the autocorrelation on the next block. Is there a way to use the information I already have to avoid recomputing the autocorrelation every time?